# WPF UserControl RealTime refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I have used [D3](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) (Dynamic Data Display) to create a chart windows that displays a live-updating line chart. 
I am trying to embed this into [WPF MDI](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/)
I had to change my chart window type from "Window" to "UserControl" to embed it, but then, when it is loaded inside an MDI Child, chart stays empty and doesn't display a live-updating line as expected.

```
            D3.MyChartControl c = new  D3.MyChartControl();
            MdiChild newWindow = new MdiChild();
            newWindow.Content = c;
            Container.Children.Add(newWindow);
```

Chart is updated every second by adding data to it via a `sendPoint()` method through an ObservableDataSource wich is bound to it (works perfectly when not in a usercontrol)

```
List<ObservableDataSource<DatePoint>> srcListLive = new List<ObservableDataSource<DatePoint>>();
public void sendPoint(DatePoint p, int graphIndex)
{          
  srcListLive[graphIndex].AppendAsync(Dispatcher, p);
}
```